# How to use montserrat font in email template?

Tags: html, email-templates, google-fonts

I am creating a new email template for one of the project. And I want to use the [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) font in my email template. But, when I receives the email the content is full of **Times New Roman** and no Montserrat font. How can I use Montserrat font in the email template?

And also I made the code with inline css. Bus does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="width:100%;font-family:montserrat;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;">
 <head> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:thin,extra-light,light,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"> 
  <title>New email</title> 
  <!--[if (mso 16)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--> 
  <style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { font-size:16px!important; line-height:150%!important } h1 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h2 { font-size:16px!important; text-align:left; line-height:120%!important } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h1 a { font-size:20px!important } h2 a { font-size:16px!important; text-align:left } h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:14px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:10px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:12px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button { font-size:14px!important; display:block!important; border-left-width:0px!important; border-right-width:0px!important } .es-btn-fw { border-width:10px 0px!important; text-align:center!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-btn-fw, .es-btn-fw-brdr, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } .es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important; width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } .es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } }
#outlook a {
 padding:0;
}
.ExternalClass {
 width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
 line-height:100%;
}
.es-button {
 mso-style-priority:100!important;
 text-decoration:none!important;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
 color:inherit!important;
 text-decoration:none!important;
 font-size:inherit!important;
 font-family:inherit!important;
 font-weight:inherit!important;
 line-height:inherit!important;
}
.es-desk-hidden {
 display:none;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:0;
 max-height:0;
 line-height:0;
 mso-hide:all;
}
.es-button-border:hover a.es-button {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-color:#ffffff!important;
}
.es-button-border:hover {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-style:solid solid solid solid!important;
 border-color:#3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3!important;
}
td .es-button-border:hover a.es-button-1 {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-color:#ffffff!important;
}
td .es-button-border-2:hover {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-style:solid solid solid solid!important;
 border-color:#e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #e5e5e5!important;
}
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body style="width:100%;font-family:montserrat;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
  <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#FAFAFA;"> 
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" color="#fafafa"></v:fill>
   </v:background>
  <![endif]--> 
   <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;"> 
     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
      <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
       <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> 
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
          <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#FAFAFA;" bgcolor="#fafafa" align="center"> 
           <table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
              <td style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;background-position:left top;" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"> 
               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                  <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/29/fa07bb493fd5106619500a4f53c013e4-full.png" height="52" width="151" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" width="151"></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
              <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:40px;background-color:transparent;background-position:left top;" bgcolor="transparent" align="left"> 
               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                  <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                   <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-position:left top;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                      
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Hello Sam</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
      <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:24px;color:#666666;">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                    
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                       <table class="es-content-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:15px;padding-top:20px;padding-right:35px;"> 
                           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                              <td align="center" style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> 
                               <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:500px;" class="cke_show_border" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="left"> 
                                <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee"> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;text-align:center;">Item Type</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;text-align:center;">Quantity</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="20%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;text-align:center;">Price</h4></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                                </thead> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">Shirt</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">2</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="20%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">5000.00</p></td> 
                                 </tr> 
         
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">Trousers</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">3</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="20%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">7000.00</p></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                                 
                               </table></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-left:35px;padding-right:35px;"> 
                           <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;border-top:3px solid #EEEEEE;border-bottom:3px solid #EEEEEE;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                              <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;"> 
                               <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:500px;" class="cke_show_border" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="left"> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;text-align:center;">TOTAL</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;"><br></h4></td> 
                                  <td width="20%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:montserrat;">12000.00</h4></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                               </table></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="center" bgcolor="transparent" style="Margin:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:40px;padding-bottom:40px;"><span class="es-button-border es-button-border-2" style="border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;background:#FFFFFF;border-width:2px;display:inline-block;border-radius:11px;width:auto;"><a href="https://viewstripo.email/" class="es-button es-button-1" target="_blank" style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;color:#34B9B8;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:15px 20px 15px 20px;display:flex;background:#FFFFFF;border-radius:7px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;line-height:17px;width:auto;text-align:center;border:2px solid #EEEEEE;border-left-width:2px;border-right-width:2px;padding:6px;"><span style="margin-top:6px;">MAKE A REPLY</span></a></span></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Wamly</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family:Montserrat;line-height:24px;color:#666666;">ABC</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table></td> 
     </tr> 
   </table> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: font does not load]

Comment: Have a look at https://caniuse.email/ Notice, that GMail and other mail clients don't support `<link>` and yet other mail clients don't support @font-face at all.

Comment: @RoToRa, Then, how can I use it, please.

Comment: I tried so many ways but unable to get the solution, please.

Comment: Looking at another site: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=font-face It looks like that GMail doesn't support @font-face either. I would say it's simply not possible.

Comment: Then, what's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing **two** things in your HTML.

**1. You dont have fall back fonts.**

Fall back fonts are needed so if a font is not found the next font in the font family will be checked for an displayed.

example:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
```

Your code had only:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat'
```

Browsers were only looking for *Montserrat* and when not found, it defaulted to Times New Roman. I have fixed up your HTML with fallback fonts (below) but do check if those are the fallback's you want.

**2. You need font definition specifically for Outlook.**

You need the below code as well in the head of the document so if Outlook is not able to find a web font, it will display a font family for your browser to choose from.

```
<!--[if (mso 9)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    table td{font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif' !important;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="width:100%;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;">
 <head> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:thin,extra-light,light,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"> 
  <title>New email</title> 
  <!--[if (mso 9)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    table td{font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif' !important;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--> 
  <style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { font-size:16px!important; line-height:150%!important } h1 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h2 { font-size:16px!important; text-align:left; line-height:120%!important } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h1 a { font-size:20px!important } h2 a { font-size:16px!important; text-align:left } h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:14px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:10px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:12px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button { font-size:14px!important; display:block!important; border-left-width:0px!important; border-right-width:0px!important } .es-btn-fw { border-width:10px 0px!important; text-align:center!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-btn-fw, .es-btn-fw-brdr, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } .es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important; width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } .es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } }
#outlook a {
 padding:0;
}
.ExternalClass {
 width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
 line-height:100%;
}
.es-button {
 mso-style-priority:100!important;
 text-decoration:none!important;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
 color:inherit!important;
 text-decoration:none!important;
 font-size:inherit!important;
 font-family:inherit!important;
 font-weight:inherit!important;
 line-height:inherit!important;
}
.es-desk-hidden {
 display:none;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:0;
 max-height:0;
 line-height:0;
 mso-hide:all;
}
.es-button-border:hover a.es-button {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-color:#ffffff!important;
}
.es-button-border:hover {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-style:solid solid solid solid!important;
 border-color:#3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3!important;
}
td .es-button-border:hover a.es-button-1 {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-color:#ffffff!important;
}
td .es-button-border-2:hover {
 background:#ffffff!important;
 border-style:solid solid solid solid!important;
 border-color:#e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #e5e5e5!important;
}
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body style="width:100%;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
  <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#FAFAFA;"> 
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" color="#fafafa"></v:fill>
   </v:background>
  <![endif]--> 
   <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;"> 
     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
      <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
       <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;"> 
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
          <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#FAFAFA;" bgcolor="#fafafa" align="center"> 
           <table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
              <td style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;background-position:left top;" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"> 
               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                  <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/29/fa07bb493fd5106619500a4f53c013e4-full.png" height="52" width="151" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" /></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
              <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:40px;background-color:transparent;background-position:left top;" bgcolor="transparent" align="left"> 
               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                  <td width="560" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                   <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-position:left top;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                      
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Hello Sam</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
      <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:24px;color:#666666;">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                    
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"> 
                       <table class="es-content-body" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:15px;padding-top:20px;padding-right:35px;"> 
                           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                              <td align="center" style="Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"> 
                               <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:500px;" class="cke_show_border" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="left"> 
                                <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee"> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';text-align:center;">Item Type</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';text-align:center;">Quantity</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="20%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:200%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';text-align:center;">Price</h4></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                                </thead> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">Shirt</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">2</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="20%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">5000.00</p></td> 
                                 </tr> 
         
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">Trousers</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="40%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">3</p></td> 
                                  <td style="padding:5px 0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #EEEEEE;" width="20%" align="left"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:32px;color:#666666;text-align:center;">7000.00</p></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                                 
                               </table></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-left:35px;padding-right:35px;"> 
                           <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;border-top:3px solid #EEEEEE;border-bottom:3px solid #EEEEEE;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                              <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;"> 
                               <table style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:500px;" class="cke_show_border" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="left"> 
                                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';text-align:center;">TOTAL</h4></td> 
                                  <td width="40%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';"><br></h4></td> 
                                  <td width="20%" style="padding:0;Margin:0;"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';">12000.00</h4></td> 
                                 </tr> 
                               </table></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td class="es-m-txt-c" align="center" bgcolor="transparent" style="Margin:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:40px;padding-bottom:40px;"><span class="es-button-border es-button-border-2" style="border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;background:#FFFFFF;border-width:2px;display:inline-block;border-radius:11px;width:auto;"><a href="https://viewstripo.email/" class="es-button es-button-1" target="_blank" style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:14px;color:#34B9B8;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:15px 20px 15px 20px;display:flex;background:#FFFFFF;border-radius:7px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;line-height:17px;width:auto;text-align:center;border:2px solid #EEEEEE;border-left-width:2px;border-right-width:2px;padding:6px;"><span style="margin-top:6px;">MAKE A REPLY</span></a></span></td> 
                     </tr> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px;padding-top:25px;padding-left:35px;"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:24px;color:#666666;">Wamly</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size:16px;font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';line-height:24px;color:#666666;">ABC</p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table></td> 
     </tr> 
   </table> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Web fonts only work on a handful of devices

```
Apple Mail
iOS Mail
Google Android
Samsung Mail (Android 8.0)
Outlook for Mac
Outlook App
```

Fonts you can use and will render in Gmail can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/1xtp98r5/

Comment: Thanks Syfer! I got it.