# Is it possible to use non-predefined fonts in a mailing designed with HTML? (Montserrat)

Tags: html, email, google-fonts

I'm creating a mailing with HTML but I'm having problems with the integration of the Montserrat font. When I run it on my local it looks perfect, but when I do the test mailing it doesn't pick up the font, instead it shows me sans-serif (the one I have in case it doesn't find Montserrat).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
      <body>
        <table
           align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;
           max-width:600px;
           padding-top:40px;
           width:100%;
           background:black;
           font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
           font-size:14px;"
        >
          ....

       </table>
      </body>
```

Is there any way to get it to take fonts that are imported from the head? I followed this thread but it doesn't work either:

[How to use montserrat font in email template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606461/how-to-use-montserrat-font-in-email-template)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know the answer. But beware that you are no longer creating HTML and CSS for browsers. You are creating it for a number of assorted email applications (desktop, web, Android, iOS...), most of which have outdated and poorly maintained HTML engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom font support in HTML emails is directly related to the support of `@font-face` declarations in email clients. And unfortunately, as reported by [Can I Email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/), support is pretty low.

[image: Can I email… @font-face]

Custom fonts work in Apple Mail (on iOS or macOS), in Samsung Email (but not with an Outlook account), and a few other regional email clients (GMX.de on iOS, Web.dev on iOS, …).

Your code is correct to embed custom fonts, but it just won't work everywhere.